# Would the 2011 27" iMac be more power efficient than my 3 year old HP PC?

Tags: power-management, power, imac

Our power bill keeps climbing higher and higher and we are looking for ways to start saving power (even if it involves quite an initial investment).

One of the things we are looking at replacing is our aging HP desktop. I am pretty sure it's the [HP Media Center m7160n](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/documentSubCategory?tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=470506). Would I see a 'noticeable' saving in power if I upgraded to an iMac? What about just a new 'regular' Dell PC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes** it will probably be more power efficient, but not 'noticeable' so.

**No** the savings will not be offset by the price of the new computer, calculate just how much electricity you will get for 1949AUD.

So I'm sorry to tell you that you'll have to find another excuse to get that nice new iMac :-)

Comment: Pretty much assumed this was going to be the case. I was more interested in whether the current iMac would be more power efficient than current Dell (or HP) PCs